# MongoDB returning error - Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR - other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am trying to run a query on MongoDB through Java Driver and I am getting this error -

```
"Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=Application.Team limit=10Tree: $or
_id == \"TEA000000006\"
TEXT : query=anonoymous, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL
Sort: { name: 1 }
Proj: { _id: 1, name: 1 }
Collation: { locale: \"en_US\", strength: 1 }
 planner returned error: Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR - 
 other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well.' on server 
 localhost:27017"
```

There seems to be some problem with the indexing I believe. 
If I do not give the `sort` or `TEXT`, it seems to work. Both together causes problem

I need the query to return records found in text search or if the ID is in the list passed (in this case, TEA0000006)

My Indices are -

```
{ 
    "v" : 2, 
    "name" : "myIndex", 
    "ns" : "Application.Team", 
    "weights" : {
         "$**" : 1, 
         "_id" : 1, 
         "name" : 1
    }, 
    "default_language" : "english", 
    "language_override" : "language", 
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}

{ 
    "v" : NumberInt(2), 
    "key" : {
        "_id" : NumberInt(1)
    }, 
    "name" : "_id_", 
    "ns" : "Application.Team"
}
```

Comment: Show at least the query and the indexes

Comment: @AlexBlex Umm isnt the output showing the query raised by Sspring Application ?

Comment: No it isn't. I see sort and projection, but not the query.

Comment: $or
_id == \"TEA000000006\"
TEXT : query=anonoymous, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL

Comment: Ah, indeed. Doesn't look like a query, yet gives some idea what the query might be.

Comment: @AlexBlex do you know how to enable logging query in Spring Boot for Mongo driver?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can ask another question about logging in Boot and tag it accordingly. Alternatively you can enable logging on db side with profiler level 2

Comment: @AlexBlex MongoDB Java Driver has some issues while preparing the query with OR and a Full Text Search.

Comment: @AlexBlex https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not possible. Refer - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13803

Answer (score 1):

For your information, you need to create separate indices for your queries to work. If you create a single compound index you'll get the error.

Example:

This work

```js
YourSchema.index({ randomValue: 1 })
YourSchema.index({ text: $text })
```

This don't

```js
YourSchema.index({ randomValue: 1, text: $text })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-create the text index without `_id` and `name`. `$**` covers all fields. 
If you need text index in these 2 fields only, remove `$**` from the index, so it should be like `{"_id": "text", "name":"text"}`